# How to pass Tkinter entry value from one frame to another through my switch frame function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame, tkinter-entry

My Tkinter application have added Notebook and inside the notebook I want to switch the frame using a button. Implemented notebook switch and frame switch. i want to take entry input from one frame of notebook to another frame when I click 'okay' button`enter code here`

I tried to pass the value as argument for frame class initialization

assign the entry filed value to a global variable

In Frame : class Tab1_Frame1 
 want to pass value from self.uidentry = Entry(self, bd=5) to class Tab1_Frame2

````
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Root class to create the interface and define the controller function to switch frames
class RootApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(NoteBook)

# controller function
    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

# sub-root to contain the Notebook frame and a controller function to switch the tabs within the notebook
class NoteBook(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()
        self.tab1 = Tab1(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.tab1, text="User Bash History")
        self.notebook.pack()

# controller function
    def switch_tab1(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self.notebook)
        self.tab1.destroy()
        self.tab1 = new_frame

# Notebook - Tab 1
class Tab1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame1)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


# first frame for Tab1
class Tab1_Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = Label(self, text="Userbash history")

        self.userid = Label(self, text ="User ID", bg="blue", fg="white")
        self.userid.pack()
        self.newWindow = None
        self.uidentry = Entry(self, bd=5)
        self.uidentry.pack()

        global uid
        uid = self.uidentry.get()
        # button object with command to replace the frame
        self.button = Button(self, text="OK", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame2))
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        if self.newWindow is not None:
            self.newWindow.destroy()
        self.newWindow = Frame(self)

        self.uid=self.uidentry.get()
        self.app = logwindow(self.newWindow, self.uid)     

# second frame for Tab1
class Tab1_Frame2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = Label(self, text="it has been changed!")       

        # and another button to change it back to the previous frame
        self.button = Button(self, text="self" , command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame1))
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.uid=self.uidentry.get()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    Root = RootApp()
    Root.geometry("640x480")
    Root.title("My Host APP")
    Root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: You can declare a `StringVar`, for example `self.myvar = StringVar()`,  in `RootApp` and set `textvariable=self.master.myvar` of `uientry`.  Then you can access the `StringVar` via `self.master.myvar` in other frame.  Of course you have to save the passed `master` to `self.master` in frame instance.

Comment: Sorry, Im not get the point, can you give simple exapmle

Comment: i have added `self.myvar = StringVar()` in **RootApp class** and defined this in `self.master.myvar=self.uidentry.get()` of **class Tab1_Frame1**.
Then i tried to read the value `self.master.myvar` from **class Tab1_Frame2**. but its not working

Comment: In your case, it should be `self.master.master.master.myvar` in class `Tab1_FrameX` because `self.master` is `Tab1` class, `self.master.master` is  `Notebook` class and `self.master.master.master` is `RootApp` class.

Comment: You should set `textvariable` of `uidentry` like `self.uidentry = Entry(self, textvariable=master.master.master.myvar, bd=5)`.

Comment: **Got this error**`self.uidentry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.master.master.master.myvar)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2101, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'myvar'`

Comment: Did you add `self.myvar = StringVar()` inside `__init__(...)` of `RootApp`?

Comment: Yes, i have added the same,please find the code  have updated

```class RootApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(NoteBook)
        self.myvalue=StringVar()```

Comment: ```class Tab1_Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.uidentry = Entry(self,textvariable=master.master.master.myvar, bd=5)
        self.uidentry.pack()```

```class Tab1_Frame2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        
        self.txt= self.master.master.master.myvalue   
        self.label = Label(self, text="vale:{}".format(self.txt))```

Comment: can you please check this and comment [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182683/tkinter-entry-widgter-value-passing-between-frame-using-master-frame-swicth-clas

Comment: You have to declare the `StringVar` before creating the frames, i.e. before the statement `self.switch_frame(NoteBook)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your button uses method from master `self.master.switch_frame()` which only switch tabs

```
self.button = Button(self, text="OK", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame2))
```

but it could use own method which will use `self.master.switch_frame()` to switch tabs and it will also move value(s) from current tab directly to new tab:

```
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.switch_frame)

def switch_frame(self):
    # get value from Entry in current Tab
    value = self.uidentry.get()

    # switch tab
    self.master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame2)

    # use value directly in new Tab
    self.master._frame.uidentry = value
    self.master._frame.label['text'] = value
```

or to `master` and other tabs can get it in `__init__` :

```
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.switch_frame)

def switch_frame(self):
    # keep uidentry in master
    self.master.uidentry = self.uidentry.get()

    # switch tab
    self.master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame2)

class Tab1_Frame2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # get uidentry from master
        self.uidentry = self.master.uidentry
        self.label['text'] = self.master.uidentry
```

Every Tab may have different code in `switch_frame`

It is good to create this variable in `master` at start with default value.

Here `master` is `Tab1` but using `master.master` you can keep it in `NoteBook`, and using `master.master.master` in `RootApp`

---

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class RootApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("640x480")
        self.title("My Host APP")

        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(NoteBook)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):

        new_frame = frame_class(self)

        if self._frame:
            self._frame.destroy()

        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class NoteBook(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook()
        self.tab1 = Tab1(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.tab1, text="User Bash History")
        self.notebook.pack()

    def switch_tab1(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self.notebook)
        self.tab1.destroy()
        self.tab1 = new_frame


class Tab1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.uid = '' # default value at start

        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame1)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):

        new_frame = frame_class(self)

        if self._frame:
            self._frame.destroy()

        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


# first frame for Tab1
class Tab1_Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global uid

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Userbash history")
        self.label.pack()

        self.userid = tk.Label(self, text ="User ID", bg="blue", fg="white")
        self.userid.pack()

        self.newWindow = None

        self.uidentry = tk.Entry(self, bd=5)
        self.uidentry.pack()

        uid = self.uidentry.get()

        # button object with command to replace the frame
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.switch_frame)
        self.button.pack()

    def switch_frame(self):
        # get value from Entry in current Tab
        value = self.uidentry.get()

        # keep value in master
        self.master.uid = value

        # switch tab
        self.master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame2)

        # use value directly in new Tab
        #self.master._frame.uid = value
        #self.master._frame.label['text'] = value

    def new_window(self):

        if self.newWindow:
            self.newWindow.destroy()

        self.newWindow = tk.Frame(self)

        self.uid = self.uidentry.get()
        self.app = logwindow(self.newWindow, self.uid)     


class Tab1_Frame2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="it has been changed!")       
        self.label.pack()

        # get value from master
        self.uid = self.master.uid
        self.label['text'] = self.uid

        # and another button to change it back to the previous frame
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="self", command=lambda: self.master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame1))
        self.button.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)

        self.uid = self.uidentry.get()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = RootApp()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey! This is a good approach, and of course, provides a great solution, so thanks for that! I had to adapt my program to use an entry, because i was trying to send a value when pressing a button and switching frames. If you have a solution to that, please let me know! Thanks!