# tkinter entry widgter value passing between frame using master frame swicth class

Tags: tkinter, frame, tkinter-entry

want to pass the value from **class Tab1_Frame1**  `self.uidentry = Entry(self, bd=5)` to **class Tab1_Frame2**

````
class Tab1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame1)
        self.mytest=StringVar()

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


# first frame for Tab1
class Tab1_Frame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = Label(self, text="Userbash history")

        self.userid = Label(self, text ="User ID", bg="blue", fg="white")
        self.userid.pack()
        self.newWindow = None
        self.v=StringVar()
        self.uidentry = Entry(self, bd=5)
        self.uidentry.pack()

        self.master.mytest=self.uidentry.get()

        # button object with command to replace the frame
        self.button = Button(self, text="OK", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame2))
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()     

# second frame for Tab1
class Tab1_Frame2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.test=self.master.mytest
        self.label = Label(self, text="it has been changed!:{}".format(self.test))
        # and another button to change it back to the previous frame
        self.button = Button(self, text="back" , command=lambda: master.switch_frame(Tab1_Frame1))
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.uid=self.uidentry.get()```
````

Comment: I see similar question third time this day.

Comment: all Tabs have access to parent/master so keep value in this variable in parent/master. And then one Tab can put value in this variable and later other Tab can get value from this variable. OR create global variable and keep value outside classes if you have problem with OOP

Comment: Thank you fauras :defined `self.mytest=StringVar()` in master and added `self.master.mytest=self.uidentry.get()` in frame and want to pass this to frame2 `self.test=self.master.mytest` but value not parsing. where i need to usee get() functiona .

Comment: if you use `StringVar` then you can't put value using `var = value` but `var.set(value)`. But You don't have to use `StringVar` to send text.

Comment: hi furas, Thank you, but still i am not able to pass value, can you give an expmple,

Comment: I don't have example. You may have other problem - when you change tabs you have to also run function in Tab2 which will get value from parent. Or more detailed: when you press button which change tab it has to run function which do: (1) put value from Tab1 to parent, (2) change visible tab, (3) run function in Tab2 which get value from parent and put in widget. You should have this method in link to duplicated question.

Comment: i am able to pass the value difectly form `frame1--> parent-->frame2` measn variable declareda in **parent**, passed the value directly from **frame1** and able to display in **frame2**
but not able to pass the value through **Entry input**. can you give a example what should i defile and frame 1 and how i can get the value in frame2,